# Recover desperate raid situation on Debian

Tags: linux, raid

I have a debian server with a RAID array of a configuration i don't know much about. It apparently had a RAID array with two 500gb disks. The main disk had two partitions, /dev/sda1 where the root FS is mounted, and /dev/sda2.

I say had because i messed up the configuration. I didn't know it was a RAID configuration, and it seemed like the second disk was unused, so i fired up fdisk and i destroyed every partition i could find on /dev/sdb. I hadn't actually understood every partition on sdb was tied to the partitions on sda..

After reboot, none of my partitions show up. The computer works, but :

```
ls /dev/sd*
```

gives out nothing. Similarly

```
fdisk -l
```

returns nothing too, and parted fails with an error, mdadm --detail --scan returns nothing too.

I tried anything i could find, but i didn't find anybody for who every device disappeared in /dev/ and i don't know what to do. The strange thing is that df outputs :

```
Sys. de fichiers      1K-blocs   UtilisÃ©    Dispo. Uti% MontÃ© sur
/dev/sda1             10080488   6255148   3313272  66% /
tmpfs                  1018372         0   1018372   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                     10240        32     10208   1% /dev
tmpfs                  1018372         0   1018372   0% /dev/shm
```

even if /dev/sda1 devices doesn't actually exist. I'm totally lost in here.

Some more info:

- It's a remote server so i can't get any of the disks out of the server
- It's running debian lenny

**EDIT:** Some more info : I can't find the disks under /dev/disk either. If they were there i guess fdisk would find them. The only place i can find info about the partitions is when i do cat /proc/partitions

```
major minor  #blocks  name

   8     0  488386584 sda
   8     1   10241406 sda1
   8     2     522112 sda2
   8     3  477620482 sda3
   8    16  488386584 sdb
   8    17  488384001 sdb1
```

I can't save anything with dd either unfortunately since i can't reach any of my disk devices ..

**EDIT 2:** Here is the [dmesg log file](https://gist.github.com/662331)

Comment: So the kernel is aware of the disks and partitions, but for whatever reason your device nodes are missing. `cd /dev && MAKEDEV sda sdb`

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the disk device nodes under /dev haven't just decided to go somewhere else? Have you checked out */dev/disk* directory and its contents? Sometimes things like that can happen if you have recently upgraded your *udev* or some other piece of system packages related to disks.

In situations like this it's essential to first backup everything you have! I mean, DO NOT try to do anything for that setup, or you may do more harm. Instead take an image of that system to USB disk or some other media, and do your recovery attempts with that copy. That way you always have your original setup around in case your recovery attempt does harm the situation even more.

You can take that recovery image with some imaging software such as [PartImage](http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page) or if you find the device nodes under /dev/disk, with `dd if=/dev/disk/pathtoyourdisk of=/path/to/your/usbdrive/recoveryimage.image bs=1M`.

Then you can fire up [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and let it find the partitions for you.

**EDIT:** This desperate-looking situation was actually due a failed operating system upgrade, as you can see from the comments to my reply. Remember, kids, when everything else fails, stay cool and analyze the situation. :-)

Comment: Hi janne, thanks for your answer. I updated my post with more info. TestDisk doesn't find any partitions either : "No harddisk found"

Comment: How about dmesg? Does it tell something about disks?

Comment: Sorry forgot the dmesg log, added it to the post

Comment: How can he take an image on USB disk? He said it is a remote server!!

Comment: @Khaled: Even remote servers can have human system administrators. ;-) 1) Phone to hosting company and explain the situation 2) mail them a USB disk by snail-mail or deliver it by yourself if you are located near it 3) have the sysadmins plug the USB drive in 4) ??? 5) Profit!

Comment: Janne: I just sent a mail to the hosting company to ask them to take the disk out and make an image. I have a backup server at that company so they should be able to use that. I somehow hoped i would find another solution but i'm kind of desperate here :)

Comment: @raph.amiard: Wow, this truly is strange. Even your dmesg says "sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
 sdb: sdb1
sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk", so it CAN find /dev/sdb1, but the partition just gets hidden for some reason. Have you recently upgraded your OS? Also, have you tried a stock kernel instead of that grsecurity kernel one?

Comment: @raph.amiard: You did a right decision. Better to take careful baby steps and make sure that whatever you do, you can take steps back, too. Patience and coolness are the keys to successful recovery, not some "HMMMM let me try that button!!" entropy-based random guesses. :-)

Comment: @janne : Yeah i recently did a big system upgrade. Could it be that ? Also i *thought* i was using a stock kernel

Comment: raph.amiard: I can guarantee you don't have a stock kernel in use. `Linux version 2.6.27.10-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv4-64 (root@kernel-64.ovh.net)` is far from `Linux version 2.6.26-2-686 (Debian 2.6.26-25lenny1) (dannf@debian.org)` my beloved Lenny tells me. And yes, the big system upgrade can very well be the reason.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your support. I backuped everything that is left to backup, so i will try to switch to a stock kernel now. Thanks again !

Comment: You're welcome. Let us know how it went. Good luck!

Comment: GAH. Uninstalled udev. MAKEDEV took the control back. Everything worked again. I'm gonna go and backup my files and install ubuntu server. Thank you for putting me on the right lead !

Comment: Great to hear your server is on its way to recovery!